# Google Apps Domains: drive migrator

Tags: google-docs, google-apps, google-drive-api

Is it possible to build a cross-domain Drive migrator?

The DocsList API was great but it doesn't support files. Google Drive SDK now works with files but doesn't return Permission emails for privacy:
[Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions#resource): we can read:

> value string  The email address or domain name for the entity. This is
>   not populated in responses.  You can use the alias me as the value for
>   this property to refer to the current authorized user.

We have many customers (Google Apps For Business) that have to migrate their own accounts (email and drive files) or change the primary domain of Apps and it's not so easy expecially for an enterprise environment.

I'll use drive SDK as well, but I have to "map" correctly shared files and I need emails of Permissions (like ACLFeed before)

Answer (score 0):

Get your ACL feeds with the DocumentList API, then migrate with Drive API.

The ids are the same, except for the root folder. But the root folder can be accessed with the alias `root` in both API